# Pra que serve o Parâmetro OPTION=3 nas conexões Banco de Dados?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, odbc

Uma conexão ao banco de dados normalmente é algo parecido com isso

```
Driver=MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver;Server=XXX;Database=XXX;UID=XXX;PWD=XXX;OPTION=3;
```

A maioria das buscas no google, sugere esse OPTION=3.
No [manual do Mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-configuration-connection-parameters.html) consta pouca coisa e tem uma relação dos possíveis números a serem utilizados, porém não tem essa OPTION 3.
Já vi outros números sendo usados em exemplos no google, mas não explicam ou comentam qual a diferença ou pra que serve. Como 16387, que tb não está na lista acima citada.

Answer (score 2):

O `Option=` recebe um valor que identifica a soma de flags que vão especificar como seu ODBC deve funcionar, o valor padrão é 0.

É possível verificar uma versão antiga da documentação em [web.archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20120120203736/http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-odbc-configuration-connection-parameters.html), onde:

`Option=3;` é correspondente a `FLAG_FIELD_LENGTH` (1) + `FLAG_FOUND_ROWS` (2)

Informações obtidas do Stack Overflow  [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407841/whats-the-option-n-in-the-mysql-odbc-connection-string/4407898#4407898).

Comment: Obrigado, e qual seria a o melhor uso agora? utilizar o padrão =0 ? (que no caso nem precisaria listá-lo)

Comment: Não sei te dizer =/